# process convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let (Ω,F,P) be a probability space and (Xn) ⊂ L1(P) and (Yn) be sequences of positive random variables which are adapted to a ﬁltration (Fn).
Suppose that the infinite sum: Y1+Y2+...< ∞ and E[Xn+1|Fn] ≤ (1 + Yn)*Xn, ∀n ∈N0, P-a.e.

And I have to Show know that (Xn) converges P-a.e.

We allready had the Theorem: Let X = (Xn) be a supermartingale with
sup E[|Xn|] < ∞. 
Then Xn → X∞ a.s. as n →∞, for some X∞ ∈ L1

Is this usefull here? My thougt was to use that Yn converge to Zero so for all c>0 there exist a N(c) such that for every n>N follows 
E[Xn+1|Fn] ≤ (1 + c)*Xn
and now define X´*j= X*(N(c)+j) 
so for c running to Zero than X´ is a supermartingale right ? 
i dont know if that kind of arguing is sensefull, corrections would be appreciated.

and know there would be left to Show that X´ holds sup E(|X´n|) < infinite
but i dont know how to Show it.. maybe someone has an idea? or an other solution idea ?

PS. sry for my bad english :P

Best Regards

Comment: Hi jessi22, welcome to MSE! It is very help to typeset your questions in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that they are more readable.

Comment: Sry, i will do it next Time!

Comment: noone with an idea? :/